# How to stop IE from launching Edge on "unsupported" websites

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Microsoft has released an update this month which prevents some websites from loading in Internet Explorer; instead presenting the following page saying "The website you were trying to reach doesn't work with Internet Explorer" and launching the webpage in Edge.

How can I disable this "feature"? I require Internet Explorer for some websites.

[image]

Comment: Edge has an "IE compatibility" mode. IE itself was completely abandoned yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Ext\CLSID`
3. Find the key named `{1FD49718-1D00-4B19-AF5F-070AF6D5D54C}` and change its value from `1` to `0`
4. Restart Internet Explorer

After some time (maybe on reboot?) this key will change back to `1` again, so you might want to put it on a Scheduled Task for on logon.